# Unwanted spacing in a barplot

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, bar-chart, seaborn

Inside my notebook I am reading data from a sqlite database using pandas.

[image]

The data is store in consecutive order, meaning there is an entry for each day (no gaps). And this is how a single entry looks like in the database:

[image]

Now when I try to plot this to a barplot (`sns` = seaborn) I get some strange gaps between data which seems to be grouped somehow:

```
data['timestamp'] = data['timestamp'].dt.date
sns.barplot(x='timestamp', y='steps', data=data, ci=None)
```

[image]

I have been using the same `datetime` format for other plots and it worked fine, so I rule that out to be the cause.
Please help me understand why those gaps occur in my plot. I would have expected the plot would look something like this (please ignore the colors):

[image]

Comment: I don't think anybody will be able to help without access to your data. Are you sure there are no gaps, or days when the step count is zero, or at least very low?

Comment: @DizietAsahi yes definitely! The example chart below is the same data.